# Force.com site user authentication

Tags: visualforce, force.com, force.com-sites

We have an existing force.com site and due to the Site Guest User changes introduced with Spring '20 it has forced us to look at our user authentication mechanism.

Does anyone have any suggested patterns for authenticating to a force.com site? The users of the force.com site have full Salesforce licenses, so the Customer Portal doesn't really apply here. Site.login() is not working with a regular licensed user so I'm struggling with navigating away from the Guest User context.

Thanks

Comment: We're working on a similar problem.  @jay, did you find a solution?